# Ingresar valores y retornarlos con una suma, a través de un botón y un input number

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy arrancando a aprender [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y tengo un inconveniente con un ejercicio, del cual tengo que hacer que me aparezca la suma total de valores con un botón y un `input` de tipo `number`.

Tengo hecho un contador, me suma los números, pero no tengo la forma de que en un párrafo, me salga la suma total (en este caso, de 6 números) entre ellos y que se detenga ahí.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",inicio);

function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#btnSumVal").addEventListener("click",sumadevalores);
}

let contador = 0;
let ingresarnumeros = 6;

function sumadevalores() {
    
    let valor;

    valor = Number(document.querySelector("#nmbSumVal").value);

    
    if (contador >= 0){
        contador = contador + valor;
        document.querySelector("#Resultado").innerHTML = `Ingresando ${contador}.`;
        ingresarnumeros--;
        
    }
    if (ingresarnumeros === 0) {
        document.querySelector("#Resultado").innetHTML = `La suma total es ${contador}.`;
    
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="nmbSumVal">Numeros a sumar:</label>
<input type="number" id="nmbSumVal" placeholder="Ingrese numeros">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnSumVal">
<br><br>
<p id="Resultado">Resultado</p>
```

Comment: A ver, necesitas que al ingresar 6 números.. ¿deje de sumar?

Comment: podrías aclarar un poco mas cual es tu duda

Comment: Sí, lo que preciso es que al ingresar 6 numeros en el input number, en el párrafo me salga la suma total de estos 6 y se detenga ahí.

Comment: Para poner más en enfasis mi problema, es que al sumar, no se detiene en hacer la suma total de los 6 numeros. Entonces, la variable "ingresarnumeros" no está funcionando, para lo cual, está creado.

Comment: ¿Algo así? https://jsfiddle.net/eyjtg20h/7/

Comment: Exacto, algo así pero dentro de lo planteado en el código, ya que noto que tengo algo mal razonado ahí, gracias!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tu código funcione has de cambiar algunas cosas. Por ejemplo,

- Si no se inserta ningún valor en el `input`no se deben actualizar los campos. Para determinar si no se ha introducido un valor, se utiliza el método global [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)
- Para realizar una acción u otra según el número de intentos realizados puedes usar un codicional `if ... else`, comparando el número de intentos actuales. Si los mismos son mayor que cero, podemos seguir ingresando números, en caso contrario no podemos.
- Para detener cuando hemos alcanzado el número intentos permitidos, establecemos el atributo [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) del botón para que no puedas seguir introduciendo números.
- El resultado se muestra cuando se ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos.

El código se puede ver parecido al siguiente:

```js
function sumar(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

let intentos = 6;
let acumulado = 0;
document.getElementById('ingresar').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const valor = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value);
  if(isNaN(valor)) {
    return;
  }
  acumulado = sumar(acumulado, valor);
  if(intentos > 1) {
    intentos--;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = `Ha ingresado ${valor}`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = `Total: ${acumulado}`;
    e.currentTarget.disabled = 'disabled';
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="numero">Número</label>
<input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="ingresar">Ingresar</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Ahí quedó, gracias!.